# Using custom shadow path on NSView

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview

Unfortunately it seems that setting the shadow attributes on the layer directly doesn't work:

```
let shadowView = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
shadowView.wantsLayer = true
shadowView.layer!.backgroundColor = .white
shadowView.layer!.shadowRadius = 50
shadowView.layer!.shadowColor = .black
shadowView.layer!.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -30)
shadowView.layer!.shadowPath = CGPath(roundedRect: shadowView.bounds, cornerWidth: 25, cornerHeight: 25, transform: nil)
```

Setting the NSView.shadow property instead works:

```
let shadowView = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))let shadow = NSShadow()
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 50
shadow.shadowColor = .black
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -30)
shadowView.shadow = shadow
shadowView.wantsLayer = true
shadowView.layer!.backgroundColor = .white
```

But `NSShadow` doesn't support a custom path. What's the easiest way to set a shadow with a custom path?

Comment: This article: https://blog.prototypr.io/what-should-you-know-about-shadows-691aa930ce02 --- scroll down to **Shadow Performance** ... is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, but that article also uses the `CALayer.shadowPath` property, which seems to work probably because the `contents` property is also being set at the same time to an image, and being able to use shadows for images only is quite limiting.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with images... see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Answer** - *after comments...*

The reason your shadow code *didn't seem to work* was because you were missing two property settings:

```
// need these two properties set
shadowView.layer!.masksToBounds = false
shadowView.layer!.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

Quick example (I moved the `shadowView` origin to 100,100 so we can see the full shadow):

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let shadowView = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.addSubview(shadowView)
        
        shadowView.wantsLayer = true
        
        shadowView.layer!.backgroundColor = .white
        shadowView.layer!.shadowRadius = 50
        shadowView.layer!.shadowColor = .black
        shadowView.layer!.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -30)
        shadowView.layer!.shadowPath = CGPath(roundedRect: shadowView.bounds, cornerWidth: 25, cornerHeight: 25, transform: nil)
        
        // need these two properties set
        shadowView.layer!.masksToBounds = false
        shadowView.layer!.shadowOpacity = 1.0  // set as desired
        
    }
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive sample, but even here, you're creating the shadow not from the `NSView` itself but from another `CALayer` (the `shapeLayer` variable). The question remains why my code doesn't work and how one can make a view drop a shadow without doing all the drawing inside a layer.

Comment: @Nickkk - whoops... guess I misunderstood what you were looking for. See the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Ah, the `masksToBounds` was the missing bit. (I had already tried `shadowOpacity` but forgot to include it in the sample.) Thanks a lot! (You may want to invert the two pieces so that the one answering the question comes at the top, or completely remove the first part.)

Comment: @Nickkk - edited my answer so it directly addresses your issue.